# How to redirect a user after registration when using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Rails 2.3 and Devise to handle user registration / authentication.

I need to redirect a user to an external 3rd party website immediately after a user signs up for an account. Been looking in the code & online but cannot see how to do this.

How can I alter the devise flow to redirect the user?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add to your **Application Controller**

```
  # Devise: Where to redirect users once they have logged in
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    "http://www.google.com" # <- Path you want to redirect the user to.
  end
```

Here is the list of Devise helpers you can use http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers

I hope that helps =)

Comment: You overrode the `after_sign_*in*_path_for`, but for OP's problem, Jason needs to override the `after_sign_*up*_path_for`, as Brett pointed out below.

Comment: Not ApplicationController but RegistrationsController.

Answer (score 57):

The answer listed as the "**correct**" answer specifically refers to after sign_in... If you want to do redirect a user after sign_up you need to override the following:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  "http://www.google.com" # <- Path you want to redirect the user to after signup
end
```

Full details can be found on [the wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29).

Comment: The code for after_sign_up_path_for seems to be a wrapper for after_sign_in_path_for. So, if you want both to behave the same, then I think overriding after_sign_in_path_for will cover both.

Comment: after_sing_in_path works if you dont have confirmation, After confirmation it redirects to root path. I have user confirmation so how should I achieve the redirection after sign up, after sign in functionality I have done for myself but I am not getting how to do for sign up.

Comment: Also, this must be done in your own RegistrationsController, not in the ApplicationController.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Devise's confirmations (meaning the user is not activated immediately after they sign up), you need to overwrite the `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` method.

```
# controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    "http://somewhere.com"
  end
end
```

Make sure to tell devise to use your RegistrationsController.

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
```

Comment: add this def after_sign_up_path_for(resource) instead of the "inactive"